# Can Bootstrap be used for a website with a smaller width than 940px as it's base?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Edit:
I want to turn a fixed width 780px width website into a responsive website using Twitter Bootstrap. Would it be inappropriate to use Bootstrap?

Can I use the span/offset system and an inner div with padding left to create the visual effect I want i.e.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span11 offset1">
<div class="innerPadding">width 780px</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help.

Edit:

Thanks for the heads up!

I came across difficulties with borders at certain screen break points. For my banner I eventually decided to use @media queries (my first use of them). On my post page I am at a dead end. Here on the li [live site](http://www.consciousoil.org/tour/) you will see the bottom borders stick out at each side, what to do?

I want the border to stretch the width of the 'span3' & 'span8', I can not put border on them as there is the gutter and 'row' covers 'span12'?

```
<div class="row border">
<div class="span3 offset1">
post content
</div>
<div class="span8">
<div class="innerPadding">
post excerpt
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try it and find out. :P

Comment: Yes you can. Give it a go!

Answer (score 0):

**Yes bootstrap can be used in this scenario.**

Just add [bootstrap-responsive.css](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive) to the head of your HTML document?

Your website will then automatically adapt to smaller/larger screen sizes.